# parseJSON issue that is causing trouble with IE 8 (and earlier)?

Tags: jquery

I have discovered that people on IE are having difficulties using a form to register for a conference.

When the user clicks "Proceed..." at the bottom of the form, a series of checks is supposed to run and then the user is supposed to be redirected to PayPal to make a payment to attend the conference. I think (although I am not sure because I'm not familiar with jquery) that the problem is the parseJSON in this block of code:

```
function check_form() {
    $('.form_error').html('');
    $('#form_submit').hide();
    $('#form_process').show();
    $.post("conference_check.php", $('#fta_form').serialize()).done(function (data) {
        try {
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);

            jQuery.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
                if (index != 'e') {
                    var element = index + '_error';
                    $('#' + element + '').html(' - ' + data[index]);
                }
            });

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        } catch (e) {
            $('#content_wrapper').html('');
            $('#process_wrapper').html(data).show();
        }

        $('#form_submit').show();
        $('#form_process').hide();
    });
}
```

**Is there any quick and simple way of altering the code above so that it will not cause issues with IE 8?**

I cannot make contact with the person who wrote the code for me as he his away for a few days but I really need a fix before then if possible as the form is live and people are clamouring to register...

Any help will be much appreciated. Please excuse me if I'm breaking any forum rules by posting as I have done above.

Comment: "I think (although I am not sure because I'm not familiar with jquery) that the problem is the parseJSON in this block of code" => No, jQuery's main selling point is that wherever there are browser quirks it works around them so you don't have to. So why do you think that? Is it a wild guess or do you have more information to share?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with these lines:

```
$('.form_error').html('');
$('#content_wrapper').html('');
$('#process_wrapper').html(data).show();
```

in my experience, IE doesn't really like the command "html", but **that only happens** when your page is rendered in quirks mode or an earlier version. There are two solutions I know of (but you should test both first before changing the live version because they might make other changes on different parts of the page):

1. replace the 'html' command with 'replaceWith', i.e like this:

   `$('#process_wrapper').replaceWith(data).show();`
2. Add this to the top of the page:

   `<!DOCTYPE html>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

(The first one works for earlier IE versions, and the second one forces the page to be rendered with IE8 which actually works fine with the 'html' command)

Comment: Thank you all for your help which has been informative for me. I don't know why I thought of it, but I updated my code to include a later version of jquery (1.10.x) and this resolved the problem so that the form functionality is working perfectly, on IE8 too. (I had previously been including 1.7.x). Now, I'm off to start doing some jQuery tutorials, I've put it off for way too long.

Comment: Good to hear. If you want to learn jQuery I strongly recommend on nettuts tutorial of 30 days to learn jQuery (by the legendary Jeffery Way). It's free and fantastic, I learned from it when I started, and it did the trick (though I already knew some javascript so maybe it'd be harder for you)

Comment: Before I saw your great advice just now, yuvi, I had found Jeffrey Way's '30 days to learn jQuery' but had never got around to working through it. I don't know javascript but know css and php fairly well which should serve as a solid launchpad. Thanks again.